Is this an error in deriving the Rayleigh-Jeans law? Kunstatter and Das's Symmetry SR and QM Ultraviolet Catastrophy
My question regards G. Kunstatter and S. Das, A First Course on Symmetry,
Special Relativity and Quantum Mechanics, Undergraduate Lecture Notes
in Physics, https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-92346-4\_8
In the discussion of the so-called Ultraviolet Catastrophe, a blackbody
radiation intensity function $I\left(\lambda\right)$ is presupposed.
The expression $I\left(\lambda\right)d\lambda$ should give "the
energy of radiation with wavelength between $\lambda$ and $\lambda+d\lambda$
emitted per unit time by the blackbody per square meter of the emitting
surface per steradian." We are then told that the intensity may
be expressed as a function of the frequency $f$ by taking into account
the relationship between wavelength and frequency. For this they give
eq 8.22 as follows:

\begin{align*}
d\lambda= & d\left(\frac{c}{f}\right)\\
= & -\frac{c}{\lambda^{2}}df\\
= & -\frac{f^{2}}{c}df
\end{align*}

They then awkwardly invert the algebraic sign and write:

\begin{align*}
I\left(\lambda\right)d\lambda= & I\left(\lambda\left(f\right)\right)d\lambda\frac{f^{2}}{c}df
\end{align*}

I don't see how this can be correct.  I think it should be
\begin{align*}
d\lambda= & d\left(\frac{c}{f}\right)\\
= & -\frac{c}{f^{2}}df\\
= & -\frac{\lambda^{2}}{c}df
\end{align*}
That is
\begin{align*}
0= & dc=d\left(\lambda f\right)=d\lambda f+\lambda df\\
= & d\lambda\frac{c}{\lambda}+\lambda df=d\lambda\frac{c}{\lambda^{2}}+df\\
= & d\lambda f+\frac{c}{f}df=d\lambda+\frac{c}{f^{2}}df
\end{align*}
Am I missing something or is this a calculation error in the book? I hope it's not simply persistent dyslexia on my part.

This is some early pioneer making a stupid choice of writing down the function, and everybody else just dancing around the inconvenience from then on. What is really happening is that $$I(\lambda)=\frac{\mathrm dW}{\mathrm d\lambda}\qquad\bigwedge\qquad I(f)=\frac{\mathrm dW}{\mathrm df}$$ for some power intensity per whatever function it is that I chose to call $W$ this time. If you do this my way, i.e. properly, then you will see that $$\frac{\mathrm dW}{\mathrm d\lambda}=\frac{\mathrm dW}{\mathrm df}\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm d\lambda}$$ that is what they have. -ve sign flips integration.

So I was correct in supposing this was not a simple mistake.  It is a complicated mistake.  As presented, I have to conclude the derivation in the book is wrong.  Contrary to my nature, I will have to revisit a proper derivation some time in the future.

The derivation from the book is technically not yet wrong. It is just a bad initial choice of representation. What I have written down is just a simple change of variables. There is no "proper derivation" because they are all like that. It is easy to make the appropriate replacements and see that what I have written down will make the standard textbook derivation become obviously correct.
